# How to clear or change a message in Redis using powershell?

Tags: powershell, redis

I am using powershell that is hooked up to jupyter redis rediscommander retwis

I am creating codes like hset snap:msg:4 to "che" from "Dax" text "Is this thing on?"

I made a mistake and msg:3 is meant to be msg:4. Is there any way to clear or edit this message?

I have tried lpop but I am new to this and do not understand all the words and what they do yet.

Comment: So I really screwed up. I think you use the hdel somewhere, but I need everything gone. How do I just clear everything?

Answer (score 0):

> I made a mistake and msg:3 is meant to be msg:4. Is there any way to clear or edit this message?

You want to **rename that key** using the [`RENAME`](https://redis.io/commands/rename/) command:

```bash
RENAME snap:msg:3 snap:msg:4
```

> How do I just clear everything?

If you wish to remove all the keys in the selected Redis database (caution!) you can do that with the [`FLUSHDB`](https://redis.io/commands/flushdb/) command. Alternatively, the [`FLUSHALL`](https://redis.io/commands/flushall/) command removes all the keys from all the Redis databases (even more caution!).